# Web Form Fill via EXCEL VBA-Can't find ID or anything to fill form

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

```js
<div class="GHNF1GMDEI GHNF1GMDGI"><div class="GHNF1GMDJK">Reference</div></div>

<div class="GHNF1GMDGI"

<div class="GHNF1GMDJK">Reference</div>
```

[adress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbiP2.jpg)    [date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDwDY.png)  html codes

```html
<input type="text" class="GHNF1GMDGM" maxlength="64" style="width: 350px;">
```

I was trying to fill a web form using different class tag  etc.. but it could not fill the form and an error occurred object dosen't support this property or method.

I tried many different ways:

```
  Sub automaticformfilling()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "xxxxxx"

        'Wait for loading
        Do While .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop   
    End With

    Set doc = ie.document        
    Set fname = doc.getElementById("j_username")
    fname.Value = "xxxx"

    Set lastName = doc.getElementById("j_password")
    lastName.Value = "xxxx"

    doc.getElementsByName("btn_submit")(0).Click
    'Set doc = ie.document
    'Set invdate = doc.getElementsByClassName("GHNF1GMDEI")
    'invdate.Value = "25"
    Set refname = doc.getElementsByName("GHNF1GMDGM")
    '.doc.getElementsByClassName ("GHNF1GMDGM")
    refname.Value = "923456"

End Sub
```

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your current error is due to the fact:

```
Set refname = doc.getElementsByName("GHNF1GMDGM")
```

is a collection, not a single element, so you can't then do:

```
refname.Value = "923456"
```

You need to use an index e.g.

```
refname(0).Value = "923456"
```

Beyond that, without url or html, can't say much about anything else that might be wrong.

---

Side note:

I would compress your two loops for page load into one:

```
While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Comment: Thansk for your support i have add image (link in first para)

Comment: I suggest you to post your HTML using code block and do not post it as an image. you can also try to loop though all the elements which using that class and try to check other properties of it for example width to identify specific control and try to set its value may help you to set the value for that element.

Comment: what happens when you make the change I mention?  Also, as per @Deepak-MSFT's comment - you can add html via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56313236/edit) and use the snippet tool - tool looks like a document icon with <> on.

Comment: i tried but fail. I have added code in above and it is related to "Refernace" so i want to know how to add value to  via vba . I couldn't identify a unique class name or ID.Please guide me

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Related to "Reference"? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Reference mean web form one of the field i need to add invoice number But i couldnt find unique ID or class for that . Thanks QHarr

Comment: anyone can help pls

Comment: What error message do you get when running my code?

Comment: Hi i checked your code it occured ,error not suuport method ,i added html code above and please check and help fix this issue thanks lot

Comment: What is the code on that line rather than the error ?

Comment: Object variable not set     How to choose index 0 or 1?

Comment: That is an error message. I need the line that is highlighted in yellow. The actual vba code.

Comment: refname(0).Value = "9234"

Comment: anyone can help in this regards